# SimpleXML Parsing Nested Namespaces - PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

I am having a small problem parsing the tags in the nested namespace called "q0:", located below.

```
//Tag that I am trying to parse
  <q0:CustomerTransactionId>
```

I am able to get to all of the "v12:" namespaced tags but not the "q0:" ones for some reason.

Thanks!

**Here is the XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <env:Header 
       xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v12:ProcessShipmentReply 
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:v12="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12">
    <v12:HighestSeverity>ERROR</v12:HighestSeverity>
    <v12:Notifications>
        <v12:Severity>ERROR</v12:Severity>
        <v12:Source>ship</v12:Source>
        <v12:Code>3058</v12:Code>
        <v12:Message>Recipient Postal code or routing code is required</v12:Message>
        <v12:LocalizedMessage>Recipient Postal code or routing code is required</v12:LocalizedMessage>
    </v12:Notifications>
    <q0:TransactionDetail xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:q0="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12">
        <q0:CustomerTransactionId>21445634</q0:CustomerTransactionId>
    </q0:TransactionDetail><q0:Version xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:q0="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12">
    <q0:ServiceId>ship</q0:ServiceId>
    <q0:Major>12</q0:Major>
    <q0:Intermediate>0</q0:Intermediate>
    <q0:Minor>0</q0:Minor>
  </q0:Version>
  </v12:ProcessShipmentReply>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**And here is my parse**

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result, NULL, NULL, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('v12', 'http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('q0', 'http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12');

    $bodies = $xml->xpath('env:Body');

    foreach($bodies as $body){

        $reply = $body->children('v12', TRUE)->ProcessShipmentReply;
        $reply2 = $body->children('q0', TRUE)->TransactionDetail;

        $custInfoArr['status'] = (string) $reply->HighestSeverity;

        if(strtolower($custInfoArr['status'])=="error"){


            $custInfoArr['invoiceNum'] = (string)$reply2->CustomerTransactionId;
            $custInfoArr['notificationSeverity']= (string) $reply->Notifications->Severity;
            $custInfoArr['notificationSource']= (string) $reply->Notifications->Source;
            $custInfoArr['notificationCode']= (string) $reply->Notifications->Code;
            $custInfoArr['notificationMessage']= (string) $reply->Notifications->Message;
            $custInfoArr['notificationLocalizedMessage']= (string) $reply->Notifications->LocalizedMessage;

        }

        $custInfoArr['trackingCode'] = (string) $reply->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->TrackingIds->TrackingNumber;
        $custInfoArr['labelCode'] = (string) $reply->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->Label->Parts->Image;
        $custInfoArr['labelCode'] = base64_decode($custInfoArr['labelCode']);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<q0:TransactionDetail>` is not a child of `<env:Body>`, it is a child of `<v12:ProcessShipmentReply>`, so you need to look for it inside `$reply`, not `$body`: `$reply2 = $reply->children('q0', TRUE)->TransactionDetail;`

The important thing to remember is that both the `->TagName` operator and the `->children()` method *only look at immediate children of a particular node*, they are not doing a "deep search" like XPath.

In fact, looking, both `v12:` and `q0:` are aliases for the same namespace ('http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12'), so the next line can just be `$reply2 = $reply->TransactionDetail`. If you just say `$reply = $body->children('http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12')->ProcessShipmentReply` rather than relying on the alias, this becomes clearer (and safer, since those aliases may change).

Incidentally, unless you're using it for something else, you can also get rid of all your XPath code (including all of the `registerXPathNamespace` calls) and just write `$body = $xml->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body` (I'm pretty sure SOAP only allows one Body per message).

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your explanation